# UI Element coordinates to UI Element properties

Tags: ios

Can someone help on how I can retrieve iOS UI Elements properties from given X,Y coordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: `- [UIView hitTest:withEvent:]` - [docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCAICB).

Comment: Google "hit testing" to get started. Without showing more effort you won't get many answers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want the  `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
 message of [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). If your `x, y` are in Window coordinates, you can use the window's view:

UIView *view = [myWindow.rootViewController.view hitTest:CGPointMake(x, y) withEvent:nil];

This will make `view` the furthest element down the view hierarchy at that location. You need to ensure your co-ordinates are in the space of the element.

You might also like `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` if you have a suspicion of the element.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is myWindow the currently viewed window by the application "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]"? if yes, I don't see itsinstance member "view"!.

Comment: Woops - sorry. You need to ask the window for it's view controller first, and ask the view controller for the view.